# Manual or guide for replacing the LCD in a Samsung Series 3 notebook?

Tags: display, lcd, laptop-repair

I cracked the screen on my Samsung Series 3 notebook, model number NP305V5A. I need to find screen replacement directions, or at least generic instructions that could work for this general type of Samsung laptop.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Can you tell us where you've looked so far? Have you check the Samsung support site?

Answer (score 1):

The screen surround is just clipped on.  Carefully un-pop it with a flat headed screwdriver.  Once this is removed you'll see 4 screws securing the screen.  Once removed you need to carefully remove the data cable thingy on the back of the screen.

A replacement is [available on Amazon.](http://www.amazon.co.uk/LAPTOP-NOTEBOOK-SCREEN-SAMSUNG-NP305V5A-AO3DX/dp/B007AH0BVY/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1341847889&sr=8-2) I have the same laptop and busted my screen in the corner.  I have successfully managed to remove my screen.

[image: Screen image]